# Why do refurbished android phones have 3 months warranty or, no warranty?

Tags: warranty

I am planning to buy an Android smartphone, but I don't know whether I should buy a refurbished phone or not. I checked many websites and most of them say that their refurbished phones function like "**NEW**", but they give only "**3 month**" warranty. If refurbished phone's performance ***is SAME as the Brand new phones***, then why they do **Not** give **1 year warranty**? I am confused !

Answer (score 1):

Refurbished phones are those that have been returned by customer due to hardware or software issues under replacement warranty.

These are then repaired, issues fixed and sold as refurbished phones by EBay etc and they carry less warranty because they are not covered by OEM or carrier warranty but warranty provided by these third parties which are lesser in duration -after all the cost is also significantly lower !

Nobody can guarantee it will or won't be as good as OEM direct sale phone performance - [caveat emptor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor)

Comment: as they are NOT giving 1 year warranty, does it mean that the refurbished phone will NOT last long as a Brand-New one?

Comment: Nobody can guarantee it will or won't. It's [caveat emptor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor)

Comment: but, if everything is working "perfectly" in a refurbished phone, then why can't it have a one-year warranty?

Comment: Like I said it's not the OEM selling it, it's EBay etc doing it and warranty costs money. Why should the company support you with complete one year warranty when you are paying **less** ? You get what you pay for